# Put \overrightarrow in section title

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, vector

I've  been trying to put a vector in the title of a section but no matter what I've tried, I keep getting the same error message (see below). I am using pdfLaTeX.

```
\section{Das Drehmoment $\overrightarrow{M}$}
```

The error message I receive is the following :

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@themark. 
 to be read again
 \crcr 
 l.71 \section{Das Drehmoment $\overrightarrow{M}$}
```

Edit:  `\vec`  works just fine, but because I've used `\overrightarrow` for all my other vectors, I don't want to break the tradition.

Comment: you don't provide a test file. this `\documentclass{book}\begin{document}\pagestyle{headings}\section{Das Drehmoment $\overrightarrow{M}$}zz\end{document}`  works in texlive 2019 and texlive 2020. If you can not update your system use `\protect\overrightarrow`

Comment: The linked duplicate seems different, but it's the same root cause of the problem - a fragile element within a moving argument.

Comment: @Werner hmm not sure every fragile command error in section error should be a dup but also that one doesn't mention that there is no problem with `\angle` or `\overrightarrow` in current releases

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I understand. Avoid having a question for `\hat`, `\overrightarrow`, `\overleftarrow`, `\vec`, `\angle`, ... in `\section` (and the same for `\chapter` and `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`... that all say "use `\protect`" as answer. At that point, they all provide the same resolution to "different" problem, and in my opinion, are duplicates.

Comment: @Werner fair enough, I'll add an updated answer at the dup though in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\section{Das Drehmoment $\overrightarrow{M}$}
zz

\end{document}
```

Works in current latex releases.

If you can not update your tex system then you can use `\protect` as you have a fragile command in a moving argument.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\section{Das Drehmoment $\protect\overrightarrow{M}$}
zz

\end{document}
```